# Adjusting speed of scrolling by using vba code

Tags: excel, vba, performance, scroll, adjustment

I have a userform that I created in Excel. Row widths can increase considerably depending on the amount of data entered by the user. However, the wider the line spacing, faster you scroll down to the next line/cell with the mouse wheel (Because it skips/jumps to the next line without fully displaying the previous line/cell, so the entered information in the previous line/cell cannot be read). Is there any way to slow down/adjusting the scrolling pace in accordance with the line width by using vba code?

I'm expecting to get more readable userform by lowering/adjusting the pace of scrolling down for the lines between 3-28.
I used below code but for some reason it did not give the result i expect.

```
Worksheets("sheet1").Activate
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll down:=1
```

Comment: No need to .Activate, just use `ActiveWindow.SmallScroll down:=1` if you want to scroll from VBA. Note that you're not changing the scroll speed, you're simply scrolling down one line.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer.That's right, the above code scrolls down 1 line after processing. But if the row is too wide, then it is not possible to read the entire row in the same font size (Think that the row is too wide to fit on the screen . )That's why I would like to ask if it is possible to slow down the scrolling speed.

Comment: Where is the row? is it in the worksheet or userform?  If it is in worksheet, try ctrl+shift+U to see all data in the cell.

Comment: It is in the worksheet. The content of the cell is listed in the formula bar by ctrl+shift+U. Thank you very much.